# DIsplay unconfirmed email after signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm new to rails, i'm trying to display the unconfirmed email that the user submitted, on a specific page after sign up like this :

`please confirm your email at this address example@yahoo.com`

this is my registrations_controller.rb

```
class  RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:prénom, :nom, :age, :gender, :tel_number, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:prénom, :nom])
  end

 private

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if params[:account][:sign_up]
      accounts_verify_email_path
  else
    accounts_verify_email_path
  end
  end
  end
```

this is what I put on the view :

```
 <%= @resource.unconfirmed_email %>
```

and i get this error :

```
undefined method `unconfirmed_email' for nil:NilClass
```

anyone knows what's the issue ?